Is there a way to configure the billing project when Dataflow (python) runs a Bigquery job?
A dataflow job (python) is running a job that query data from Bigquery. The cost of the queries run in bigquery rely on the same project as the job. Is there a way to setup the billing project of the bigquery job?
I´ve found the Apache beam Java SDK has a parameter to specify the billing project, but I didn't found an equivalent parameter for python.

Please check temp_dataset in https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html
